# Find the general solution (GS) of the DE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

i) $(1 + t)y^{\prime} = ty+t+t^2$

ii) $y^{\prime} + \cot(t)y = 2cost$

Not sure how to start...

Comment: We don‘t do your homework.

Comment: They are both linear first order odes, which can be solved by the method of integrating factors.

Answer (score 1):

$$2) y'+\cot(t)y=2\cos(t)$$
Rewrite it as
$$ y'+\frac {\cos(t)}{\sin(t)}y=2\cos(t)$$
Multiply by $\sin(t)$
$$ y'\sin(t)+\cos(t)y=2\cos(t)\sin(t)$$
$$ (y\sin(t))'=\sin(2t)$$
Integrate...

Try to do first equation on your own and post your attempt...

Members will correct it...